# Ansible lint reports "Package installs should not use latest"

Tags: ansible, ansible-lint

I've finally started using Ansible Lint to ensure I'm up to date and not missing things and I've found it reporting a curious error/notice.  When I use `dnf` to install a package, I've been using `state: latest` as it's for a system bootstrapping process that I may run multiple times on the same instance, particularly during development.  I always want the latest package installed in this scenario however Ansible Lint is reporting:

```
Package installs should not use latest
```

While I'm confident that in my use case I'm ok, is this simply because in the interest of "idempotency" one would normally not want this behaviour?  Or is there another reason?  If they're always going to report this, then why even offer the `latest` status option?

Comment: Would the anonymous '-1' care to elaborate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ansible-lint` is opinionated. You may not always agree with those opinions. There are other people who feel that this error from the `package` module [should be removed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/479).

In any case, you can [configure the linter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/configuring/configuring.html) to ignore this particular issue. Create a `.ansible-lint` file in your playbook directory that contains:

```
skip_list:
  - '403'
```

Comment: Appreciate the insight into the background, but even more so, how to hide specific notices by ID, great help!

Comment: I'm happy to have the opinions but they really need their rationale explained so I can make an informed decision to agree or disagree in my case. Your issue link thread helped, thanks.

Comment: @MikeLippert: Just came across this question and looked up the rationale. I found the following: "In production environments, you should set state to present and specify a target version to ensure that packages are installed to a planned and tested version." [Source](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/package-latest/#problematic-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
- name: Upgrade distribution packages
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    state: latest # noqa package-latest
    upgrade: dist
    autoremove: true
    update_cache: true
```

The `# noqa package-latest` comment tells ansible-lint to ignore the rule.